# mySql join Tables with key

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
+----+----------+------------
| id | restaurant| ...       |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | one       | ...       | 
|  2 | tow       | ...       |
```

And now for the restaurants I want to add in hours of operation for each. Now from what I have read it would be bad to have a new column and call it hours and then have a `varchar` and have something like

```
"9:00-22:00,10:00-20:00,10:00-21:00"
```

And then when I pull this data into my app later split it at the commas to make an array. Not 100% sure why this is bad, but I know that I am not supposed to do that right?

So I was thinking making a new table called "Restaurant_Hours" and have it look like this

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+
| id | restaurant| mon       |tue         | ect...
+----+----------+------------+------------+
|  1 | one       | 9:00-22:00|10:00-22:00 |
|  2 | tow       | ect.      | ect.       |
```

Is this strategy of making the new table and having it like the way I showed best? And is this also not the correct way of doing things. And then restaurant would be my unique each in each so I could get the hours that way?

Comment: No. See normalisation.

Comment: what's best depends on how you need to query the data

Comment: The restaurant_hours table is heading in the right direction, but you'd be better off having each row have a restaurant_id (not name), day of week (1-7 being Sunday through Saturday), and separate open & close TIME fields. You would have one (or more) rows for each day a restaurant is open. (I say "or more" because some restaurants close for a couple hours between morning and evening hours.)

Comment: @Uueerdo you comment is a good answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: @Uueerdo could you post as answer and give a bit more detail, much appreciated

Comment: Come on. Try creating a table along the lines described by Uueerdo. You can use an integer or a string for the day if the week. It will make very little difference. But use a time data type for the start and end times.

Comment: @Strawberry integer is better than string, otherwise people end up with chores to order their days of week properly (as opposed to alphabetically).

Answer (score 0):

The base of what I'm thinking is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `restaurant_hours` (
  `restaurant_hour_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `restaurant_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `day_of_week` TINYINT NULL,
  `opens_at` TIME NOT NULL,
  `closes_at` TIME NOT NULL,
  `hours_desc` CHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

Of course, restaurant_id should be a `FOREIGN KEY` to `restaurants`.`id`, and you *might* want a `UNIQUE` constraint on (restaurant_id, day_of_week, hours_desc). If they have special hours for holidays, you might want to use day_of_week == 0 as a "flag".

... or if you're feeling really ambitious, have it also reference some sort of "day_descriptions" table, where 1-7 correspond to Sunday-Saturday, and >=8 can be used to signal things that may need calculated by year (specific holidays).

Edit: hours_desc is intended as things like "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", etc...

Even without that, a query to find out "what's open when" would go something like this:

```
SELECT r.restaurant 
FROM restaurant_hours AS rh
INNER JOIN restaurants AS r rh.restaurant_id = r.id
WHERE rh.day_of_week = DAYOFWEEK(@theWhen)
AND rh.opens_at < TIME(@theWhen) 
AND rh.ends_at > TIME(@theWhen)
;
```